# Combine serveral images into one Live-USB

Tags: linux, grub, livecd, liveusb

I wanted to know if it's possible to combine at least two systems into one image :

Example :

I have a Debian image (*.iso) and a Clonezilla image (*.iso) and I want to make one image and the GRUB (installed into the image) let me choose between Clonezilla or Debian.

Is it something easily doable or should I make a fully custom image ?

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was looking for. I tried YUM and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate partitioning the memory stick and then load each OS on the seperate partitions as if they were seperate devices.

http://www.wikihow.com/Partition-a-Thumb-Drive

First time posting on here so I hope it helps.
Regards,
Ivan G-S